# Applying formula to each column R openxlsx

Tags: r, excel, excel-formula, openxlsx

I've an excel workbook with multiple columns which have dates as the column name. Is there a way to apply formulas to each column in openxlsx. I need a way to dynamically populate each column with the appropriate excel formula as the no of columns is huge.

This is sheet 1. **Please Note: The letter at the top of the columns names signify the excel column names and the numbers at the start of each row are the excel row numbers.**

```
      A          B           C          D
   Product   1/1/2020     1/1/2019   1/1/2018      
1     1          1          10          1          
2     2          2          20          1           
3     3          3          30          10            
4     4          2          10          5            
5     5          4           5          10
```

This is sheet 2

```
      A         B          C            D           E
   Product    Skill     1/1/2020     1/1/2019   1/1/2018      
1     1         W2         1            1          10          
2     2         W45        20           1           0           
3     3         W0         40           5           0            
4     4         W1         50           5           1            
5     5         W2         2            2           1
```

This is the resultant sheet.
The excel formula for cell C1 "='Sheet1'!B1*'Sheet2'!C1"

The excel formula for cell D1 "='Sheet1'!C1*'Sheet2'!D1"

The excel formula for cell E1 "='Sheet1'!D1*'Sheet2'!E1"

```
       A         B          C            D          E
    Product    Skill     1/1/2020     1/1/2019   1/1/2018      
1      1         W2         1           10          10          
2      2         W45        40          20           0           
3      3         W0         120         150          0            
4      4         W1         100         50           5            
5      5         W2         8           10          10
```

**As I'm new to openxlsx is there a way to do this using the write_formula function. I want to automate the process as the number of columns is very large. Thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

I try to give a solution. You can check whether it is acceptable.

```
library(openxlsx)
st1 <- read.xlsx("example.xlsx",colNames = FALSE,sheet = 1)
st2 <- read.xlsx("example.xlsx",colNames = FALSE,sheet = 2)
st3 = st2
st3[3:5] = st1[2:4] * st2[3:5]
# This means the multiply operation of two sheets
# st4$X3 = st1$X2 * st2$X3
# st4$X4 = st1$X3 * st2$X4
# st4$X5 = st1$X4 * st2$X5
```

Comment: Thank you for  the solution but I'm looking for ways which will use the write_formula function of openxlsx.

Comment: Fine. But I still want to suggest  if there is no more restriction, we had better to focus on how to slove the problem rather than which function has to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to wrap `writeFormula()` in a `for` loop.

```
library(openxlsx)
library(glue) #I find this easier than paste(), ymmv
wb <- your_workbook
sheetname <- sheet_you_are_working_on

col_start <- some_number
col_end   <- another_number

row_start <- third_number
row_end   <- fourth_number

for(c in col_start:col_end}
  writeFormula(wb, sheet_name, 
               glue("='Sheet1'!{col}{row}*'Sheet2'!{col}{row}",
                    col = letters[c], #might need to make your own letters if more than 24 columns
                    row = row_start : row_end
                     )
                )
}
#example with numbers
for(c in 4:5}
  writeFormula(wb, sheet_name, 
               glue("='Sheet1'!{col}{row}*'Sheet2'!{col}{row}",
                    col = letters[c], #"C" and "D" are within letters()
                    row = 1:5
                     )
                )
}
```

If you want, you can get even fancier across sheets by having a second loop that defines your sheet names.